# Google Drive Android API - Invalid DriveId and Null ResourceId

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have been battling this code the whole day without luck. I started by following this code [sample](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/BaseDemoActivity.java) from Google.

The problem is that the folder gets created successfully but inside **onResult()**, I always get a DriveId or resourceId that is invalid or incomplete. That means I cannot create a file inside the folder I created. Here is the code I am using:

```
public class CreateFolderActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
            .setTitle("MyAppFolder").build();
    Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient()).createFolder(
            getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet).setResultCallback(callback);
}

final ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult> callback = new ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveFolderResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create the folder");
            return;
        }

        // this value is always invalid with ending == operators
        Log.d("DRIVEID", "Created a folder: " + result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId());
    }
  };
}
```

Whenever I run this code, I get the following id which appears incomplete:

```
CAESABi2VyCCzdWOuVMoAQ==
```

I don't know what is happening here!

I have Google'd around and read of adding listeners to listen for completion events but none of them seem to work.

I have seen nearly similar questions on SO on this but none of them work for me.

I manually copied the FolderId through my browser after the app created it and then pasted to my android code and the app created a file successfully. But this is not how things should work.

Am I suppose to wait for the sync to complete and if so, how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any solution arround ? I have the same problem creating a folder with drive file picker.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your problem can probably be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874657/unpredictable-result-of-driveid-getresourceid-in-google-drive-android-api/31553269#31553269). The DriveId you're getting is OK, but you should not handle it directly. It is a '*preliminary*' DriveId that changes after the object has been committed (again, see [SO 22874657](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874657/unpredictable-result-of-driveid-getresourceid-in-google-drive-android-api/31553269#31553269)). You can test it comparing DriveId you're getting vs. DriveId you'll get in 'onCompletion(CompletionEvent event)'.

This is just one of the side effects of GDAA's logic, shielding you from on-line / off-line network state resulting in unpredictable delays. You just have to rely on callbacks.

But I am surprised that you can't use this 'preliminary' DriveId (in case of a folder) immediately as a parent of another object (folder/file). I have never experienced it, passing the 'preliminary' DriveId immediately to another GDAA method.
It is different in case of the ResourceId. That one is secondary in the GDAA and is used only if you go outside of the device. It is not known to the GDAA until the object is committed (uploaded).

I used similar logic (creating folder / file tree) in this [demo](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo) (see MainActivity.createTree() method). You're welcome to dig in it.

There is a related problem discussed in [SO 34318220](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318220/google-drive-android-api-completion-event-for-folder-creation/34373475#34373475).

Good Luck