# Google Drive API for Android returns empty file

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api, drive

I'm  using google drive api to store some files in google drive app folder, However on some devices when I try to download the files it simply returns the files with size of  0 byte.

upload code:

```
/**
 * It's a blocking method
 *
 * @param file the file to upload to google drive.
 */
private boolean uploadToDrive(@NonNull File file) {
    final DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = Drive.DriveApi
            .newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
            .await();
    // If the operation was not successful, we cannot do anything and must fail.
    if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        Logger.t(TAG).e("Failed to create new contents.");
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, we can write our data to the new contents.
    Logger.t(TAG).i("New empty contents created.");

    //Creates a file in app folder with provided metadata.
    final DriveFolder.DriveFileResult driveFileResult = Drive.DriveApi
            .getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
            .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, getDatabaseMeta(file.getName().replace("temp-", "")), driveContentsResult.getDriveContents())
            .await();

    if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        Logger.t(TAG).e("Error while trying to create the file in app folder.");
        return false;
    }

    final DriveApi.DriveContentsResult contentsResult = driveFileResult
            .getDriveFile()
            .open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null)
            .await();

    if (!contentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        Logger.t(TAG).e("cant create a file in app folder");
        return false;
    }

    final DriveContents driveContents = contentsResult.getDriveContents();

    if (!writeFileToDrive(file, driveContents)) {
        Logger.t(TAG).e("Cannot read or write to file");
        return false;
    }

    final Status status = driveContents.commit(mGoogleApiClient, null).await();

    if (!status.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        Logger.t(TAG).e("Cannot upload the file to drive");
        return false;
    }
    // TODO: 2016-01-19 Store this to use this this file later.
    Logger.t(TAG).e("getDriveId:" + driveFileResult.getDriveFile().getDriveId().encodeToString());
    return true;
}
/**
 * Write the source file to destination drive contents file.
 *
 * @param file          the source {@link File} to read from.
 * @param driveContents the destination {@link DriveContents} to write to.
 */
private boolean writeFileToDrive(File file, DriveContents driveContents) {
    try {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];

        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(driveContents.getOutputStream());
        int n;
        while ((n = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
        in.close();
        is.close();
        out.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

download code:

```
@Nullable
private DriveContents downloadFileFromDrive(@NonNull DriveId driveId) {

    final DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = driveId.asDriveFile().open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, new DriveFile.DownloadProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(long bytesDownloaded, long bytesExpected) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onProgress() called with: bytesDownloaded = [" + bytesDownloaded + "], bytesExpected = [" + bytesExpected + "]");
        }
    }).await();
    if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        Logger.t(TAG).e("Cannot download the file");
        return null;
    }
    return driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();
}

/**
 * Writes the drive contents to the destination file.
 *
 * @param source
 * @param destination
 * @return true if the write is successful.
 */
private boolean writeFileToDisk(@NonNull DriveContents source, @NonNull File destination) {
    try {
        final InputStream in = source.getInputStream();
        final BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destination));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];

        int n;
        while ((n = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

The uploaded file is downloaded correctly in emulators and most devices, but on some devices it is downloaded with 0 byte file size.

Actually when I upload a file from a device with this problem and then I request to download it with the same device again, I receive a file with zero length from cache, if I try to download that file from another device which has this problem it just download it without an issue.

I think something is wrong with its caching strategy, It just check if the file already exists in the cache and returns it with 0 byte size.

The devices I have this issue with are api 21 and below.

Google Drive Api 9.2.1

Google Play Services 9.4.52 Date: 19 Jul 2016 Latest version

Answer (score 0):

I have same Error. And I found that, DriveId i want to download is a 'preliminary' DriveId (Follow this [resourceID of file is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355665/google-drive-android-api-invalid-driveid-and-null-resourceid)). I saved that 'preliminary' DriveId to my Database, and cant download that file.
I fix this by receiving CompletionEvents when create and edit file, to get real resourceID of file when GDAA commit file to Drive (by [receiving Completion Events](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/completion)). Sorry for my bad English.